# React Native & Keyboard : How do I toggle the keyboard in useEffect without using TextInput?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard

I'm writing react native using functional components.

I want to toggle and render the keyboard value without using TextInput.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Keyboard.addListener('handleKeyPress', handleKeyPress)
  }, []);
```

How do I do that? Please show me a sample code.

Comment: you can use an Text input and set it style is invisible

Comment: Well, is it the right way tho? It looks like we are trying to go around it.

Comment: it's the easiest way to implement. BTW, i dont see any built-in functions of Keyboard for openning it manually without using text input

Comment: i usually match the style of TextInput with background

Comment: I see. I will think about it. Thank you guys so much for your inputs ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the style of TextInput with background!